# Get Attachment Category Name

Tags: functions, custom-taxonomy, attachments, categories

How can I call the name of an attachment category?

Something that would look like `<?php get_attachment_category_name ?>` or `$attachment->category_name`

This would simply output the name of the category, which was created using the below function:

```
function add_categories_to_attachments() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'attachment' );
}
add_action( 'init' , 'add_categories_to_attachments' );
```

Comment: Where will you be calling it from? `attachment.php` template file?

Comment: Just from the media library. I think this is close to what I need:

`<?php $attachment_data = wp_prepare_attachment_for_js( $attachment->ID ); 
echo '.get_cat_name($catid).'; ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was found here: http://www.wprecipes.com/how-to-display-category-name-without-link

For my purposes, I needed to define the category function and then call it by name-only inside the `php echo`:

```
     <?php
$category = get_the_category($attachment->ID);
    echo 'html goes here';
    echo ''.$category[0]->cat_name.';
    ?>
```

Additionally, to help eliminate space or punctuation in the category name, it can display the slug instead:

```
<?php
$category = get_the_category($attachment->ID);
    echo 'html goes here';
    echo ''.$category[0]->slug.';
    ?>
```